# How to size bigger in Plot Pie Graph?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a figure bigger size but I couldn't do it.

How can I show the figure more bigger?

Here is my code snippet shown below.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

kill_df.plot(kind='pie', 
        y = "race",  
        autopct='%1.1f%%', 
        startangle=90, 
        labels= kill_df["index"], 
        fontsize=14)

plt.title('Killed People According to Races',color = 'purple',fontsize = 15)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1))
plt.savefig('images/image8.png')
plt.show()
```

Here is the screenshot of figure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
# set the size in inches
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
fig.savefig('test2png.png', dpi=100)
```